# Worksheet specific color change

Tags: excel, vba

Help appreciated.  It reads the value of c on the "fivemin" sheet just fine but when I switch to another worksheet while running the macro it changes the color of the active sheet.  How can I specify the color change to the "fivemin" sheet?

Thanks for the help in advance,  Cy

```
Private Sub COLOR()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Excel.Worksheets("FIVEMIN")

Dim c As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("fivemin")
For Each c In ws.Range("E6:E11").Cells

        If c.Value < 0 Then
        Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
             Else
         Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
             
        End If
    Next c
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: Put a `.` in front of each unqualified instance of `Range` and `Cells`.

Comment: Btw, the `.Cells` in `For Each c In ws.Range("E6:E11").Cells` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Just enough `With ws`